# Show that a process is no semimartingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

_Hello everyone! 
I got a little question about how to show that the process $X_t:=|B_t|^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is NOT a semimartingale.

So far I tried to apply Ito. Since if $X_t$ was a semimartingale so is $F(X_t)$ for every $C^2$ function $F$. Unfortunately I found no appropriate function. I tried to use $F(x)=x^3$ but, trying to show that $Y_t:=|B_t|$ is no semimartingale is in fact the same problem.

The only thing I found out so far, is that $X_t$ is NO local martingale (since if it was, it would be positive, starting in 0, hence being a supermartingle, hence being convergent, hence having a contradiciton).

Thank you!

Comment: Except that |B| **is** a semi-martingale.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose that $X_t := |B_t|^{\frac{1}{3}}$ *is* a semimartingale. Then, we have by Itô's formula

$$|B_t| = X_t^3 = 3 \int_0^t X_s^2 \, dX_s + 3 \int_0^t X_s \, d \langle X \rangle_s. \tag{1}$$

Moreover, Tanaka's formula shows

$$L_t = \int_0^t 1_{\{B_s=0\}} dL_s = - \int_0^t 1_{\{B_s=0\}} \text{sign}(B_s) \, dB_s + \int_0^t 1_{\{B_s=0\}} \, d|B|_s$$

where $(L_t)_{t \geq 0}$ denotes the local time of $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ at $0$. Using Itô's isometry and Fubini's theorem, it is not difficult to show

$$\int_0^t 1_{\{B_s=0\}} \text{sign}(B_s) \, dB_s = 0$$

Consequently, we find by $(1)$

$$\begin{align*} L_t &= \int_0^t 1_{\{B_s=0\}} \, d|B|_s =3 \int_0^t X_s^2 1_{\{B_s=0\}} \, dX_s + 3 \int_0^t X_s 1_{\{B_s=0\}} \, d \langle X \rangle_s = 0\end{align*}$$

as $\{X_s=0\} = \{B_s=0\}$. Hence, again by Tanaka's formula,

$$|B_t| = \int_0^t \text{sign}(B_s) \, dB_s.$$

Since the right-hand side defines a one-dimensional Brownian motion (and the left-hand side is, obviously, not a Brownian motion since it is positive), we reach a contradiction. Consequently, $|B_t|^{1/3}$ is not a semimartingale.

*Remark* The proof is compiled from *Philip E. Protter: Stochastic integration and differential equations*, Theorem 71, Chapter IV. There, the result is shown for any continuous local martingale.

Comment: Thank's a lot! Giving the Tanakas formula a quick lock (never heared about it before), I guess I got your argument. And I also learned that $|B_t|$ is a semimartingale! Again, thx!