# Do there exist diffusions that do not solve any SDE?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Diffusions are continuous time stochastic processess having continuous paths and satisfying the strong Markov property.

I know it is possible to characterize some diffusion processes as solutions to SDEs.
However I think I read somewhere that not all diffusions can be written as solutions of an SDE.
Is there any reference to confirm the last statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, not all strong Markov processes with continuous sample paths solve an SDE. Here is an example:

Let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Brownian motion. The process $X_t := |B_t|^{1/3}$ is not a semimartingale (see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/632352/36150)) and, hence, it doeesn't solve an SDE. (If it would solve an SDE, it was a semimartingale.) On the other hand, $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Markov process (very similar reasoning as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1194074/36150)). Since $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has continuous sample paths, this already implies that it has the strong Markov property; this follows from an approximation procedure, see e.g. Theorem A.25 in *Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes* by Schilling & Partzsch. In summary, $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a process with continuous sample paths satisfying the strong Markov property and failing to solve an SDE.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear answer!

Comment: @A-B-izi You are welcome.